# Bottom Navigation View shows error in xml file. But cannot find what is the error

Tags: android

I am trying to add a bottom navigation view of support library in my app. Here is the code below. I am getting error like

```
  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #52: Binary XML file line #52: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
```

But my xml code is looking fine also. And the gradle dependency version of support and appcompat are also equal. I couldn't figure out the error. Can someone help me to figure out the issue?

XML code is

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:design="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/rl_container">
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/drawer_item"
    app:itemBackground="@color/brand_black"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/drawer_item"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer"/>
   </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And my java code is

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

   //getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);
   // getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    ///getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    BnavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);

    SharedPreferences sP = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    String user = sP.getString("user", null);
    sessionManager = SessionManager.getInstance(this);

    if(user == null ) {
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Splash.class));
        return;
    }

    BnavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            onDrawerMenuItemClicked(item);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Error report is given below

```
04-22 11:23:13.665 5112-5112/me.entri.entrime E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                            Process: me.entri.entrime, PID: 5112
                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{me.entri.entrime/me.entri.entrime.activities.Home}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #52: Binary XML file line #52: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2680)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2741)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1488)
                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6176)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
                                                             Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #52: Binary XML file line #52: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
                                                             Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #52: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
                                                             Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:143)
                                                                at me.entri.entrime.activities.Home.onCreate(Home.java:87)
                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6688)
                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2633)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2741)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1488)
                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6176)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
                                                             Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationItemView.initialize(android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl, int)' on a null object reference
```

and my gradle dependencies are

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use only this dependency:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
```

Remove other two dependencies:

> compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.0.1'
>  compile
>   'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.1'

Comment: This is not the answer. I found the error, error was with the menu.xml file. Any ways thanks for answering my question :)

Comment: I hate it when somebody comments like "Found the answer. Never mind". *smh*